# Code crash if there is no print on the loop, how can I fix?

Tags: c++

My code below is to do a filter in a PCM file (a music file full of short ints), apply a filter and make an output.

When I execute it (press F9), there is sometimes in which it will succeed and others that it will crash my executable, but if I put a printf/cout on it, making the program last longer, it will increase its chances of not crashing.

Its very bizarre, I don't know what is happening so I can't fix it, please take a look below in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

short *vetor_entrada, *vetor_saida;
char nomeArquivoEntrada[50] = "sweep_100_3400.pcm", nomeArquivoSaida[50] = "saida.pcm";
size_t tamanhoArquivo;

int lerEntrada(){
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;

    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen ( nomeArquivoEntrada , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) return -1;

    fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (pFile);
    rewind (pFile);
    tamanhoArquivo=lSize/sizeof(short);

    vetor_entrada = (short*) malloc (sizeof(short)*lSize);
    vetor_saida = (short*) malloc (sizeof(short)*lSize);
    if (vetor_entrada == NULL) return -1;

    result = fread (vetor_entrada,sizeof(short),lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize) return -1;

    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
}

int escreverSaida(){
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen (nomeArquivoSaida, "wb+");
    fwrite (vetor_saida , sizeof(short), tamanhoArquivo, pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
}

void processamento(int k){
    float *vetor_coeficientes = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float)*k);
    short *vetor_amostras = (short*) malloc (sizeof(short)*k);
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        vetor_coeficientes[i]=(float)1/(float)k;
        vetor_amostras[i]=0;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<tamanhoArquivo;j++){
        vetor_amostras[0]=vetor_entrada[j];
        short aux=0;
        for(int m=0;m<k;m++){
            aux += vetor_coeficientes[m]*vetor_amostras[m];
        }
        vetor_saida[j]=aux;
        for(int n=k;n>0;n--){
            vetor_amostras[n] = vetor_amostras[n-1];
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    lerEntrada();
    processamento(32);
    escreverSaida();
    return 0;
}
```

The loop in "processamento" function (the 'j' increasing one) is the main problem (as far as I've seen), if I put printf("%d",j) in it, probably won't crash.

Here is some PCM file to test it with:
https://www.mediafire.com/?3l3iq8553jcy7dk

How can I fix the crashing?

Comment: please learn to step through your code with a debugger

Comment: I did, when I do it, it runs without crashing

Comment: You seem to have some odd uses of the various sizes you have in your code.  As an example `lSize` is the number of bytes in the file.  The number of shorts would be half that, although you try to read double that size from the file.  Since you've tagged this C++ you might consider using vectors and avoiding malloc altogether.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I would like to use vectors but I went to malloc because I couldn't get those vectors to work with 80k indexes (which are the indexes of my example) any sugestion?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa - That is hard to believe that you can't create a vector of 80,000 longs and floats.  What probably happened is that you were stepping out of bounds (see the answer you accepted), and `vector` will have undefined behavior just like plain old using malloc if you made this mistake.

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa - In addition, your `escreverSaida` function does not return a value when it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks  wrong

```
    for(int n=k;n>0;n--){
        vetor_amostras[n] = vetor_amostras[n-1];
```

The range of vetor_amostras is 0 .. k - 1. You are assigning to [k].

Comment: Ops! Thanks man, its a very silly mistake but I probably would take a long time if it weren't for you! ;)

Comment: +1 for the answer, and @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa : `for (int n = k; n-- > 1;)`

Comment: @WhozCraig didn't get it, where shall I put this?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa it replaces the for-loop head that is pointed out in this answer.

Comment: It wont work that way, I have to put n = k-1 to work :P, but thanks for your answer

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa I take it you skipped the `n--` in the *middle* expression (the conditional). The increment clause is left *out*. No biggee. As long as it works. best of luck.